# Plugin to map Unity VR app input in real-time

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, virtual-reality, oculus

I need to create a plugin that would show in a separate dashboard what is being pressed on Vive / Oculus controllers. The plugin needs to work with any Unity-based VR app.

Is it possible to pass those value and have a plugin or a standalone app that works?

Comment: I am assuming a simple "Yes, it is possible" is not the entire answer you are looking for, you need to try and do it yourself, when you run in to a problem you can't solve come back with that specific problem and we will be glad to help.

Comment: Sure. I guess the main point is can you have two separate screens with a plugin or does it have to be a standalone app running in parallel to the main vr app.

Comment: Just to add to that, can a separate windows app track the input coming from a VR application or is the input data exclusive to the VR app once that is running?